# Javascript don't substitute html in rails + Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Still learning how to use Ajax in Rails. 
I have a simple controller:

```
class PagineController < ApplicationController

  def cerca
  end

  def trova
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render layout: false }
    end
  end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
  get '/cerca', to: 'pagine#cerca'
  post '/cerca', to: 'pagine#trova'
```

This is trova.js.erb:

```
$('#search_table').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'search_result') %>");
```

This is cerca.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag '/cerca', remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name], placeholder: 'Inserisci parte 
        del nome del gioco' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Cerca' %>
<% end %>


<h1> Results </h1>

<div id="search_table">
  <p>Here the partial</p>
</div>
```

and this is the _search_result.html.erb

```
  <p> I'm running well </p>
```

I'm expecting that, when i submit a search with the button, "Here the partial" will be substituted with "I'm running well". 
But this is not happens.
In the log i see that _search_result.html.erb is correctly rendered, so all should run.

Why don't?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've resolved (for future references if someone needs), using different js:

```
document.getElementById("search_table").innerHTML = "<%= j render 'search_result' %>"
```